# Calling a Web method from acsx file using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I know that the web method of ascx file cannot be called from jquery, so i created one aspx page (test.aspx) and rendered that ascx page(mainmenu.ascx) in my aspx page by adding

Even then my web method is not been called which is now in test.aspx.cs.

Any help is kindly appreciated.

Comment: rendered the ascx page in aspx page by adding <%@ Register TagName="test" TagPrefix="asp" Src="MainMenu.ascx" %>

Comment: Please show how you're making the call.